# Geodesic Digons in Reductive Spaces

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, homogeneous-spaces, polygons, geodesics

Consider a naturally reductive homogeneous space $M$ of positive curvature. Is it necessarily the case that there exists a geodesic digon whose interior angles sum to less than $2\pi$? Angles are measured by any metric compatible with the canonical connection on $M$. It's straightforward to show that this is the case if $M$ is symmetric.

EDIT: Equivalently, does there exit a digon around which the holonomy is non-trivial?

Comment: Assume that $\gamma$ is a geodesic, $X$ Killing vector field whose restriction to $\gamma$ is not identically zero and that there are $p \neq q \in \gamma$ such that $X(p)=X(q) = 0$. Let $F^t_X$ be the flow of $X$. Then for small values of $t$ the angles of the two geodesics $\gamma$ and $F^t_X(\gamma)$ at $p,q$ are small.  Is this related to your question?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Holonomia. I was thinking about your previous suggestion concerning Berger spheres. What you're describing here are conjugate points. The problem is that you can't be sure that the geodesics  $F_X^t(\gamma)$ pass through $q$, even for small $t$. Hence    $\gamma$ and $F_X^t(\gamma)$ may not form a digon.

Comment: But the geodesic $F^t_X(\gamma)$ do pass through both $p,q$ since this points are fixed points of $F^t_X$ being zeroes of $X$.

Comment: There's no such result. The best you can do is have the geodesics leave $p$ but only get arbitrarily close to $q$.

Comment: I think you are confusing the concepts of Jacobi and Killing vector fields. Namely, what you said is true for conjugated points i.e. when $p,q$ are zeroes of a Jacobi vector field along $\gamma$. But I am speaking about a Killing vector field $X$.  So $F^t_X(\gamma)$ is another geodesic through $p$ and $q$ for every value of $t$. What you can object is the existence of such geodesic $\gamma$, the points $p,q$ and the Killing vector field. But browsing Ziller's paper http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02567391 it seems to me that there are a plenty of such things.

Comment: Isn't it a general result that the restriction of a Killing field to a geodesic is necessarily a Jacobi field?

Comment: Yes, but in this case the points $p,q$ are fixed along the geodesic variation induced by $X$. Do you agree that $p,q$ are fixed points of the Killing flow $F^t_X$?. Now let $\gamma(s)$ the parametrization of $\gamma$ such that $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma(1)=q$. Then, for fixed $t$, $F^t(\gamma)(s)$ is a parametrization of $F^t_X(\gamma)$ such that $F^t(\gamma)(0)=p$ and $F^t(\gamma)(1)=q$. Such Killing vector fields are called "isotropic Killing vector fields".

Comment: So you're saying that in any naturally reductive compact Riemannian homogeneous space there exists a pair of points conjugate to each other which can be connected by a 1-parameter family of geodesics? I've never seen such a result.

Comment: Yes, and I think so as concequence of the existence of these Isotropic Killing vector fields. Since the Euler Characteristic of your space is positive any Killing vector field has some zero. Then it is not so hard to expect the existence of such Killing vectors fields with more than one isolated zeroes. Here you can see more about this Killing vector fields: http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0926224509000217/1-s2.0-S0926224509000217-main.pdf?_tid=2a4e800c-a244-11e5-8de4-00000aacb35d&acdnat=1450085115_da81c1b7e31d7a1d6b899305d0b4ffa9

Comment: The statement is true for symmetric spaces but I need to investigate if it's been generalized to homogeneous spaces.

Comment: For the Berger sphere $S^3 \subset C^2$, regarded as the unit sphere of C^2 endowed with a U(2)-invariant metric (not necessarely the canonical one) there are geodesics $\gamma$ starting at $(1,0)$ and ending at $(-1,0)$ not contained in the first factor $(*,0)$. Then the flow of the Killing vector field $X=(0,i)$ i.e. $F^t_X(z,w) = (z,e^{i t} w)$ produces a 1-parameter family of geodesic through $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$.

Comment: That's fine but I need a result for general compact naturally reductive spaces. Your approach will work provided that it can be shown that there exists a pair of isotropically conjugate points in the space. This isn't apparently from Ziller's paper.

Comment: After trying with Ziller's paper I admit that indeed the existence of a pair of isotropically conjugated points in a naturally reductive space of positive curvature (NRSPC for short) is not clear. Anyway, I have a nice idea to show that such points do exists. I will post it as soon as I have time to check all details. In the meantime notice that that if there is a NRSPC $G/K$ without a pair of isotropically conjugated points then its symmetry rank in the sense of http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.3184  is 0 o 1. In particular the dimension of $K$ is positive.

Comment: I've looked at Ziller's paper as well. He says that there are plenty of isotropic Jacobi fields but doesn't elaborate. I've written to a few people  and asked them about this but haven't as yet got a reply. I look forward to seeing your argument as well.

Comment: @Holonomia Why do you say the Euler characteristic is positive? If $G/H$ is a quotient of compact Lie groups, this happens if and only if $G$ and $H$ have the same rank. But there are positively curved homogeneous spaces with rank difference 1, e.g. Aloff-Wallach spaces.

Comment: @Sebastian Goette: You are right, I  had a lapsus. Odd dimensional spaces have zero Euler characteristic, so I do not know why I say so. Sorry. In any case as soon I have some time I will post an answer showing that any NRSPC have a geodesic $\gamma$ and a Killing vector field inducing a non zero Jacobi of $\gamma$ with  two zeros.

Comment: Trying to write down my idea I have a problem I can not fix. Thanks to this problem I realized that the OP question as negative answer. The real projective plane $RP^2$ is a naturally reductive homogeneous space (for the definition see http://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.4936v2.pdf) of positive curvature without such digon.  Of course as the OP posted the question it seems that the he is thinking about simply connected NRSPC but he omited the hypothesis of being at least oriented. So perhaps it is better to edit the question.

Comment: I don't think you're correct here: the real projective space is a symmetric space and so all conjugate points are isotropic. By the way, any simply connected manifold is automatically orientable.

Comment: The Killing vector fields of $RP^2$ come from Killing vector fields of the sphere $S^2$. Notice that they vanish at two antipodal points. So when such Killing vector field acts on $RP^2$ then it vanish just at one point. Hence along a given geodesic a Killing vector field of $RP^2$ vanish at most at one point. If you do not think I am correct here then please try to draw a digon on a half sphere whose interior angles sum to less than 2π . Put one vertex $p$ at the north pole. Where you will put the second vertex $q$ ? where are the two geodesic sides?

Comment: The second vertex is also the north pole. I'm allowing for digons which don't have distinct vertices.

Comment: Then you allow closed geodesics!.  Indeed, a geodesic starting and ending at $p$ is a closed geodesic since naturally reductive spaces are GO spaces. So your problem reduce to the existence of a closed geodesic. It is well known that a closed geodesic exists in any compact Riemann manifold.

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. I'm allowing digons which consist of two closed geodesics joined at a point.

Comment: So in this case the answer to your question is positive. As in the case of $RP^2$, the geodesics of a NRSPC are closed. So you can do the same thing as for $RP^2$. Namely,  take two different geodesics starting at the same point $p$ and this is the digon you are looking for, isn't it?

Comment: It's not the case that all geodesics in a NRSPC are closed.

Comment: All geodesics are closed !. As you can see in Internet naturally reductive spaces are GO spaces i.e. geodesics are orbits of 1-parameter Lie subgroup of isometries. If a geodesic is not closed then the closure gives you a totally geodesic flat torus hence you have a flat totally geodesic submanifold. Since you are assuming positive curvature i.e. you are in a NRSPC then your geodesic IS CLOSED !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34046/discussion-between-oliver-jones-and-holonomia).